# Make My View Center Bottom in its Parent View?

Tags: android, layout, view

How could I make my view (like an `ImageView` other `View`) center bottom in its parent view ? As in this picture below.

The parent layout could use any layout, `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`.

I Know that `MapView` has the center and bottom property, but I don't find the property in `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`.

Thanks very much .

My English is not good, please forgive me my grammar error..

```
_____________________
|                   |
|                   |
|        ___        |
|       |___|       |
|         |         | ______  center
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
---------------------
          |
          |
          |
          |

        center
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution does actually depend on what layout the parent is. If it's a RelativeLayout, you can use:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

If it's a FrameLayout or LinearLayout:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
```

Comment: If you mean center bottom like asked, you need also android:layout_alignParentBottom in RelativeLayout or use android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" in LinearLayout

Comment: @Niko Ah, the question is much clearer after editing. :) I'll revise my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are wrong. In the question he wants to put the image not in the bottom of the parent. He wants to put the image exactly in the center but he also wants the bottom of the inner image to be centered vertically.

The solution should be like this. You should know the height of the image ,say 80dp. and put a bottom margin of half of the height, 40dp in this case.

```
<Button 
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />
```

If it's a FrameLayout or LinearLayout:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />
```